# Simplify $|2x^{2}+3x-2| $ so we can obtain it and control it in terms of $|x-1|$

Tags: real-analysis

First example I worked, I had $|2x^2 + x - 3|$ after some manipulations and simplifications I obtain: $|x-1|(2|x-1|+5)$. The final answer is in terms of $|x-1|$ with multiplication between two expressions.

So going back to the question my best attempt is this:

$$|2x^2+3x-2|=...=|2(x-1)(x+1)-3x|=|2(x-1)(x+1)-3x+3-3|=|2(x-1)(x+1)+3(x-1)+3|$$

$$=|(x-1)(2(x+1)+3)+3|=...=|(x-1)(2x+5)+3|=|(x-1)(2x-2+7)+3|=|x-1|(2|x-1|+7)+3$$

The problem I'm having is I have that $+3$ at the end. I need to simplify in a way so that I get no added constants out side the two expressions i.e. something like "$|x-1|(t|x-1|+y)$" . I tried different simplifications but this is the best I can do.

Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why is the +3 a problem?  Notice what happens when you plug in $x=1$ to your first example and then this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we could somehow find $t,y$ for which
$$|2x^2+3x+2|=|x-1|\ |t(|x-1|+y)|.$$
Then putting $t=1$ the left side would be $7$ and the right side $0.$

Note that this same problem will occur for any form of the right side having $|x-1|$ as a factor.